# Gmail Search Operator for general "today"

Tags: gmail-search

Does anyone know if there is a search operator for the current date?

I'm in the process of cleaning out a bloated email inbox and would like to be able to search for only the current days email without typing the date.

I assume there is a command for the current system date, but I can't see to find it.

Answer (score 10):

There's no "today" search operator, but you can filter to the last 24 hours with the `newer_than` operator.

```
in:inbox newer_than:1d
```

(Unfortunately "0d" doesn't work.)

That should work for what you want to do.

Source: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190

Comment: Makes one wonder why isn't there, though? I use "newer_than:1d" myself, but it would be nice to have "today" be an operator - and it would be nice if it started at 00:00 (24 hour time) on the current day and not 24 hours prior to the moment you're looking at it. Would also be nice to have a "this week" which starts on Sunday (or Monday, depending on settings) at 00:00 rather than exactly 168 hours ago, and a this month, this year, etc.